# Склонение фамилии Чуб-Швец

Tags: склонение-фамилий

Склоняется ли мужская фамилия Чуб-Швец? По правилу: если первая часть не употребляется как самостоятельное слово, она не склоняется. Но Чуб вполне употребляется. Можно тогда склонять обе части? Чуба-Швеца?

Comment: "Говоруха-Отрок" склоняется в обеих частях (можно по книгам посмотреть), а эта фамилия - такой же структуры.

Answer (score 1):

[Словарь собственных имён русского языка](https://books.google.ee/books?id=i5e8DwAAQBAJ&pg=PA32&lpg=PA32&dq=%D0%B4%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B9%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5%20%D1%84%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B8%20%D1%80%D1%83%D1%81%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D1%85%20%D1%85%D1%83%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B2&source=bl&ots=fs07-WcZkD&sig=ACfU3U1HWUxPoUpRlKgbrE5F1EjUU9CEkg&hl=ru&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwj0k5aYqZfvAhXNs4sKHbwEBVk4ChDoATACegQIBhAD#v=onepage&q=%D0%B4%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B9%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5%20%D1%84%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B8%20%D1%80%D1%83%D1%81%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D1%85%20%D1%85%D1%83%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B2&f=false) (Ф. Агеенко):

> **В русских двойных фамилиях** склоняются обе части, если их окончания поддаются склонению, например: СОКОЛ**О**В-МИКИТ**О**В, Сокол**о**ва-Микит**о**ва (рус. писатель); ГОЛЕН**И**ЩЕВ-КУТ**У**ЗОВ, Голен**и**щева-Кут**у**зова (рус. поэт, филолог, литературовед), но: СОКОЛ**О**В-СКАЛ**Я**, Сокол**о**ва-Скал**я** (рос. художник).
> Если первая часть не употребляется как самостоятельное слово, она не склоняется: Д**Е**МУТ-МАЛИН**О**ВСКИЙ, Д**е**мут-­Малин**о**вского (рос. скульптор); ГРУМ-ГРЖИМ**А**ЙЛО Владимир, Грум ­Гржим**а**йло Владимира (рос. учёный-­металлург); БОНЧ-БРУ**Е**ВИЧ, Бонч-Бру**е**вича (рос. военный деятель).

Именно на эту же информацию ссылается и [Грамота](http://gramota.ru/slovari/info/ag/sklon/).

Правильно: Тана-Богораза, Степняка-Кравчинского, **Чуба-Швеца** (и *Чуб*, и *Швец* склоняются).

*София Чуб-Швец, воспитанница тренеров Энвера Эмирасанова и Анатолия Чуба-Швеца, показала высокий результат...*